# AWS SageMaker + Tensorflow + GPU

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, gpu, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to extract ELMo embeddings and running the code on AWS SageMaker and TensorFlow. The code runs fine on cpu instance in SageMaker **but I want to run it on GPU**. Below are the steps I performed and error listed:

1. Started AWS SageMaker instance: ml.p3.8xlarge - it has 8 GPUs
2. Started JuperterLab and selected conda_tensorflow_p36 for the notebook
3. Ran the following code:

!pip3 install **tensorflow-gpu==1.15**.
!pip3 install "tensorflow-hub<0.5.0"

```
url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2"
embed = hub.Module(url)

def defineEmbeddings(start, end, extractions):    
    embeddings = embed(extractions[start:end],signature="default",as_dict=True)["default"]
    return embeddings
def scoreExtractions (embeddings):

    config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.9
    with tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config) as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
        x = sess.run(embeddings)
    return x
```

I get the following error with sess.run(embeddings)

UnknownError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unknown: **Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.**
     [[{{node module_apply_default_1/bilm/CNN_1/Conv2D}}]]
     [[module_apply_default_1/truediv/_155]]
  (1) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node module_apply_default_1/bilm/CNN_1/Conv2D}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

But following works with the above setup:

```
with tf.device('/device:GPU:3'):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(c))
```

Based on my reading up on this issue on StackOverflow, I also tried to use **tensorflow-gpu = 1.8.0** also and with that, I'm getting the error in import tensorflow as tf :

**ImportError**: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?